# "Converged in iteration 1200" or "converged on iteration 1200"?

Tags: prepositions

I have a simple line:

> the process converged **in/on** iteration 1200

Which one is the correct preposition to use here?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to know for sure with so little context provided. [Both prepositions can be used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+converged+on%2C+it+converged+in&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20converged%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20converged%20in%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: There's no other context to provide I think. That is the full sentence. All things equal, I'll use "on" which is the most used one according to ngram.

Comment: There is almost **always** more context that can be added. Surely this sentence isn't in isolation! I reckon it is part of a larger paragraph, or an answer to somebody's question.

Comment: No, it is the output from a code. It is literally that single line that gets printed when the iterations converge.

Comment: Well, that's context. That would help me know which preposition to use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can't be definitively answered without more context (regarding "the process" and "iteration"), even if unavailable as the OP has indicated.

Comment: You want me to describe the computational process that iterates and eventually converges? How would that help? This is a valid English sentence. The context has already been explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also consider: *the process converged **at** iteration 1200* and *the process converged **after** 1200 iterations*

Neither of the options you proposed striked me as flat out wrong - just not as common as **at.**

I would be more likely to use **in** for ranges of non-convergent iterations, and **at** for specific iterations.

> *"The process swung wildly in the first 100 iterations.  At iteration 73, the error was 1157%.  For the next few hundred iterations, the error decreased to less than 10%, and after 1000 iterations, it was less than 5%.  The process finally converged to within tolerance at iteration 1203."*

Comment: BTW:  I know _to within tolerance_ seems to have two prepositions in a row.  Weird but common.  I don't have the right linguistic vocabulary to fully explain it, but I think of _"within tolerance"_ being the name of a binary status - *within* isn't really acting as a preposition

Answer (score 1):

The most common preposition would be *on* iteration N.  The reason is that we're talking about a loop, which iterates through the same code repeatedly.  **On** the Nth iteration of that code, something happens.

It's similar to other expressions of repeating action:

> And **on** the seventh day He rested.
>
> Every week **on** Sunday we have a picnic
>
> The ball will go around and around the track.  **On** the fifth time it reaches the starting point, hit the button.

*At* might also be fine.

> At the 1200th iteration, the process halted.

*In* the Nth iteration would instead imply that the convergence happened *in the middle* of the iteration.  This sounds incorrect for the context, since it seems more like the convergence is an expected feature of the code, and was processed normally.